# SQL Math Operation In Correlated Subquery

Tags: sql, subquery, visual-foxpro

I am working with three tables, basically, one is a bill of materials, one contains part inventory, and the last one contains work orders or jobs. I am trying to find out if it is possible to have a correlated subquery that can perform a math operation using a value from the outer query. Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
SELECT A.work_order,A.assembly,A.job_quantity,
    (SELECT COUNT(X.part_number)
    FROM bom X
    WHERE X.assembly = A.assembly
    AND (X.quantity_required * A.job_quantity) >= (SELECT Y.quantity_available FROM inventory Y WHERE 
Y.part_number = X.part_number)) AS negatives
FROM work_orders A
ORDER BY A.assembly ASC
```

I am attempting to find out, for a given work order, if there are parts that we do not have enough of to build the assembly. I'm currently getting an "Error correlating fields" error. Is it possible to do this kind of operation in a single query?

Comment: Can you do the calculations in a derived table that you then join to the main table in the FROM clause?

Comment: @TamarE.Granor - Would you mind giving an example of what you were thinking? I can't seem to figure out how it would work with a derived table.

Comment: I'd have to understand your data better, I think. But the question is basically whether you can create some intermediate tables via query that contain data you need and then join them to the main table. I'm not sure you can looking at your example, but start by trying to do the task in a series of queries. If you can make that work, post that here and we can help you turn it into a single query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving the subquery to a join, something like this:

```
   SELECT a.work_order, a.assembly, a.job_quantity, n.negatives
   FROM work_orders a JOIN (SELECT x.part_number, COUNT(x.part_number) as negatives
                     FROM bom x JOIN work_orders b
                     ON x.assembly = b.assembly
                     WHERE (x.quantity_required * b.job_quantity) >= (SELECT y.quantity_available 
                                                                       FROM inventory y WHERE 
                                                                       y.part_number = x.part_number)
                    GROUP BY x.part_number) n
                    ON a.part_number = n.part_number
                    ORDER BY a.assembly ASC
```

Or create a temporary cursor with the subquery and then use it to join the main table.
Hope this helps.

Luis